# SSRS filter TOP N with others

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a datase with man rows and couple groups/subgroups. Child group can have many records and i need to show only 5 first and others have to be in row "Other".
I managed to filter group like this:

```
Expression: Product
Operator: Top N
Value: 5
```

But now other rows are not visible. Maybe somebody had the same problem or jus simply knows how to solve it? My matrix looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+
|                    | Date                    |
+                    +----------+--------------+
|                    | Quantity | All Quantity |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Employee | Total   |          |              |
+          +---------+----------+--------------+
|          | Product |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Employee is a group, Product is child group. Date is column group.

EDIT:

I maged to create second identical group and filter it using filter like this:

```
Expression: Product
Operator: Bottom N
Value: =Count(Fields!Product.Value) - 5
```

But it does not work correctly. It allways shows one product and that product is from the list where top 5 is.

Comment: Another problem sill remains: filter is applied before sorting, so i get wrong top items...